# Clang-format disable comment alignment for end of scope markers

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am trying to configure clang-format's **AlignTrailingComments** key to differ this situations

```
int a = 5;  // Comments
int b = 7;  // Are
int c = 10; // Aligned
```

This is the case I wan to keep

```
for() {
  if() {
    for() {

      /*
       *  A very long code
       */

    } // for
  } // if
} // for
```

It tries to align the comments after closing braces which I want to keep as they are.

So how can I make it work?

I tried to find a solution in the documentation, but couldn't do that
I hope there is a feature to solve it, but maybe it is not supported yet?

Comment: If you need this comments at the end of `for` `if` ... this means you write code which has to many lines per function. I rely  recommend you to extract functions form complex long functions instead having those `// for`. Quote from Linus Torvalds (for C): [If you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed anyway, and should fix your program](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst).